# Google analytics for different .html files in the same domain

Tags: html, google-analytics

Let's say that my website is www.myWebsite.com.
I have set up google analytics in index.html file properly and I get all the statistics fine in my dashboard.
Now my website has also got other html files, in the folder: www.myWebsite.com/folder/file1.html and www.myWebsite.com/folder/file2.html.
I want to track these pages too, and get how many view each page has.

In order to do this, do I have to use **the same** scripting code from analytics that I got for www.myWebsite.com ? And should the dashboard appear each page's views separately? Or do I have to set up different code for these pages?

I hope that I explained my problem well. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to include the Analytics tracking code into the source code on every page you wish to track. This means including it in `index.html` and `file1.html` etc.

You can find more info in the Google Analytics [help page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

You have to include generated code in every page that you wish to track.